# How can I control the ethernet packet rate in FPGA?

Tags: windows, udp, fpga, ethernet, ttl

I am sending UPD packets from PC (Windows 10 10.0.19044) to the FPGA board (Xilinx Virtex-7 FPGA VC707 Evaluation Kit).

I see the FPGA receives data in burst. It means that I receive 64 packets continuously with the FPGA clock rate. After that, I don't get anything for a while, and again I receive 64 packets, then this process happens over and over. There is no data loss and I get all packets correctly (the average data rate is correct and equal to the target rate), but this type of data receiving (Burst mode) causes issues for the subsequent processing cores. According to block RAM limitation in size, if I import all burst packets to FIFO to manage the input rate for the following processing cores, FIFO becomes full and data is lost. The burst rate is much more than the processing rate, So I have to control the bursts.

How can I decrease the number of burst packets (64)? Is this limitation due to the PC or the FPGA?

Ethernet data send rate from PC which have been tested: 20 Mb/sec - 200 Mb/sec - 800 Mb/sec
(In all these rates the burst length is 64 packets)

PC spec:
Intel(R) Core i7-10700K 3.80GHz
Ethernet: Intel Ethernet Controller I225-V

Processing Board Spec:
VC707 Evaluation Kit

Comment: Change the FPGA to a PC (tell the first PC to send packets to the second PC) and run wireshark on the PC, it will show you received packets with timing. You can also run wireshark on the first PC but it will show you send timing, not receive timing, and if the first PC's network card is affecting the timing the first PC might not know it

Answer (score 0):

what you describing sounds like as bursts are generated by PC/driver/chipset. It may not be related but this particular Ethernet Controller had issues:

[I225-V driver issues](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000057261/ethernet-products/gigabit-ethernet-controllers-up-to-2-5gbe.html)

It may be worth while trying the version of the driver they recommend. Or rent a proper Ethernet test gear.